# how do I fix Excel error scenario Manager?

Tags: excel, system, analysis

Basically I have been trying to do a scenario manager task for a what if analysis for hours and hours for a project due tomorrow. Despite having no arrays or data tables on my sheet I still get the error “some changing cells are part of an array or data table and cannot be changed” every single time I try to run a scenario manager task. There is absolutely no info online about this error as far as I can see. Please Help
Thank You!!
[My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrv1C.png)
[The error I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F277Q.png)

Any Help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: where is the error located and what is the formula associated?

Comment: The error pops up after I click show on the scenario manager pop up. It's not on one particular formula it happens on every single cell I attempt to change

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and fixed it by removing the merged cells that were being referenced by the scenario.

I had a title area on the sheet for the scenario title, and to make this look good I had merged a few cells. I then had set the title in the scenario (and therefore, then merged cells were referenced)

To fix the problem, I unmerged the cells so that the scenario was no longer referencing any merged cells.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).